# Rainbow Six tag inconsistencies. What do?

Tags: support, retag-request

I just updated the tag [rainbow-six-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rainbow-six-series) with a summary and main wiki. One element I feel is important in a series tag is listing all the games that would be included in that series. If available, I provide tag links.

This lead me to look up the available tags, and of the three available, all three show minor issue.

---

[rainbow-six-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rainbow-six-3): In this case, the tag itself is valid. However, there is only one question being asked;

> [What is the differance between Rainbow Six 3: Gold and Rainbow Six 3: Athena Sword?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/142441/rainbow-six-3-gold-edition-vs-rainbow-six-3-athena-sword)

The original version was released on computer as Rainbow Six 3: Athena Sword, and while it was later released as "Rainbow Six 3" on console, the console version has *some* different content, and as I have observed previously, this in itself suggests the use of a separate title tag.

---

[rainbow-6-vegas-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rainbow-6-vegas-2): Simply an inconsistency issue, but I am sure the extra two characters will not break the character limit. The tag should be [rainbow-six-vegas-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rainbow-six-vegas-2), assuming deliberate consistency. This is the way it is spelt on the box, and in fact, every rainbow six game apart from the cancelled "[Rainbow 6: Patriots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Clancy%27s_Rainbow_6:_Patriots)".

---

[rainbow-six-siege-beta](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rainbow-six-siege-beta): A tag created for a question regarding the beta of Rainbow Six Siege. That said, beta is a "pre-release" version, released to allow the game to be tested by a wider community before release. Furthermore, since this version will be replaced with the release version upon launch, there will come a time (within several months) where this tag will not relate to anything available to the general public. For this reason, I propose replacing it with [rainbow-six-siege](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rainbow-six-siege). The tag wiki could make note of its current beta form, and be updated later.

---

**TL;DR:**

- [rainbow-six-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rainbow-six-3) should remain, but a summary should be included to inform users that Rainbow Six 3 is the console version of Athena Sword.
- [rainbow-six-3-athena-sword](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rainbow-six-3-athena-sword) should be created, and used to replace the tag on [the rainbow-six-3 question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/142441/rainbow-six-3-gold-edition-vs-rainbow-six-3-athena-sword).
- [rainbow-6-vegas-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rainbow-6-vegas-2) should be replaced with [rainbow-six-vegas-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rainbow-six-vegas-2).
- [rainbow-six-siege-beta](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rainbow-six-siege-beta) should be replaced with [rainbow-six-siege](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rainbow-six-siege).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with most of this, but for the record (and as mentioned in the linked question) [rainbow-six-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rainbow-six-3) as referred to is [Rainbow Six 3: Raven Shield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Clancy%27s_Rainbow_Six_3:_Raven_Shield), which was expanded in (not released as) `Athena Sword` (this being the first expansion, not a separate game).
These were both combined in Rainbow Six 3: Gold (which was essentially what the GOTY releases these days seem to do).

`Rainbow Six 3` is also the name of the release on consoles, as you note, though there are some differences in included content.

Based on the way we've previously treated stuff like [risen-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/risen-2) (full name `Risen 2: Dark Waters` - showing that we have previously snipped extra title off for the shortened tag) and console-separate versions of games such as [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) vs [minecraft-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-console), I'd recommend we leave [rainbow-six-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rainbow-six-3) as the tag for all PC versions of R6:3 and create a [rainbow-six-3-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rainbow-six-3-console) tag *if it ever comes up*.

I can't imagine us getting any further questions about the original Xbox version of R6:3 (and the only question is about the PC version), so we're probably safe leaving it as is.